# How to get base URI of xdmp:unquote($record)

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I get the record from database by `fn:doc()` and the `quote` and `unquote`. But it gives empty result if I try to get `base-uri`.

```
 let $Doc := fn:doc("/aaaa.xml")
 let $nodc := xdmp:quote($Doc)
 let $unquote := xdmp:unquote(xdmp:quote($Doc))
 return
  $unquote/fn:base-uri(.)
```

Answer (score 3):

Constructed nodes do not have URIs.

When you `xdmp:quote` XML, the string output has no connection to the input XML. It is just a string. When you call `xdmp:unquote` with a quoted XML string, the output is a new constructed node and has no URI. So the new document constructed by `xdmp:unquote` has no URI.

Comment: if it has no connection to the input xml than the record could be updated in separate transaction by xdmp:eval. But it produce deadlock.

Comment: That's a different question. By all means ask a separate question about updates and deadlocks, with a simple reproducible test case.